# Assignment to a new variable when deleting an element in a slice yields unexpected result

Tags: go, append, slice

I am seeing some unintended behaviour when trying to delete an element within a slice. Below is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    y := append(x[:3],x[4:]...)
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ALn3chTBIY)

the output is:

```
[1 2 3 5 6 7 8 8]
[1 2 3 5 6 7 8]
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 5 6 7 8]
```

Why is the result not what I expected?

In other words since there is no assignment to change the value `x` I would expect it to have the same initialized value but for some reason it doesn't and has the same value as `y` with the last element duplicated. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `append` function operates in-place when enough space is available. Slice away the capacity to avoid this behaviour:

```
y := append(x[:3:3],x[4:]...)
```

Comment: Note, do not just blindly do this unless you fully understand what is going on. This style of use of `append` to remove items is a bit of a hack/trick and part of that is so that it avoids (most) unnecessary copying. If you want/need efficient removal of items you likely want something other than simple slice (maybe just a map, or a combination of a [map and a slice](https://code.google.com/p/rsc/source/browse/regexp/regmerge/sparse.go#14) if you want ordering).

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens, when you append, x is changed.

```
x = [1,2,3,  4,5,6,7, 8]
    [1,2,3] [5,6,7,8] # 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th elements are changed
     x[:3]    x[4:]

x = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,8]
```